# Can't get data from model to appear in template Ember.js

Tags: templates, ember.js, models

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/FNn4R/4/ I can't get the outgoings model (a model with messages outbound) to display in the template.

HTML

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="messages">
    Hello <b>{{App.username}}</b><br />
    {{#each outgoings in model}}
    <h4>{{outgoings.vehicle_reg}}</h4>
    <p>{{outgoings.message_subject}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

JS

```
App.MessagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Outgoings.all();
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('header-messages', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'header'
        });
        this.render('messages', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'content'
        });
    }
});

App.Outgoings = Ember.Object.extend();

App.Outgoings.reopenClass({
    all: function() {
        var outgoings = [];
        var apiPage = "messages";
        var parameters_string = "action=outgoing";
        var url = "http://do-web-design.com/clients/carbuddy/index.php/api/";
        var url = url + apiPage + "?" + parameters_string + "&username=" + "will" + "&password=" + "1234";
        // console.log(url);
        var response = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "text json",
            success: function(data){
                return data;
                // return JSON.parse(data)
                alert('Its working');   //It will alert when you ajax call returns successfully.
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' | ' + errorThrown);
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            response.forEach( function (outgoing) {
                outgoings.push( App.Outgoings.create(outgoing) );
            });
        });
        return outgoings;
    }
});
```

My Ajax call is getting data but its just not copying it into the model and or sending it to the template.

Comment: Try using Ember's `pushObject` instead of `push` (`outgoing.pushObject(App.Outgoings.create(outgoing))`

Comment: Also if your backend returns a Collection of objects you should use a ArrayController for the job like: App.Outgoings = Ember.ArrayController.extend();

Comment: I made those changes but I'm still not getting any data coming through :(

Unrelated issue too: I get an error when I try and perform the AJAX calls from different domains. If there a way to resolve this? http://jsfiddle.net/26Xaf/1/

Comment: It would be make it easier for people to help you if you narrow down your problem into a smaller code sample/fiddle that exhibits the issue.